# Is there an official list of all 626 experiments? I remember a poster-y thing existing

Tags: lilo-and-stitch

Is there an official list of all 626 experiments? I remember a poster-y thing existing...

It was a foldable paper that was divided into blue boxes, and listed the experiments... But I'm not sure if it listed them all...

I guess it might have been the [Experiments Tracker](https://www.picclickimg.com/00/s/OTQwWDE2MDA=/z/BwMAAOSw27df2l1e/$/Lilo-Stitch-The-Series-Aloha-Cousins-Experiment-_57.jpg)? And now looking at it more, I'm more and more convinced, but is there no larger one?

Answer (score 2):

There have been many shortened/truncated lists over the course of the series, stemming from Lilo's Pokemon-trackeresque [scrapbook](https://liloandstitch.fandom.com/wiki/Lilo%27s_Experiment_Book) of them. But if you want a comprehensive list of all of them, they're only shown in one place: in the end credits of [Leroy](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/stitchipediaalilostitch/images/b/b7/Experiment_List.jpg) and [Stitch](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/stitchipediaalilostitch/images/1/19/Experiment_List2.jpg).